# Add DOCTYPE to retrofit POST xml request body

Tags: java, xml, retrofit2

I'm using retrofit 2 and java to make API calls.  I have successfully made some POST requests but trying to add a new call has stumped me.

The body required is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE ourapi SYSTEM "nameOfTheDTD.dtd">  
<mainPart version="7.0">  
   <some other stuff>
</mainPart>
```

I can build the mainPart of the request body using the usual @Root, @Path and @Element simpleframework.xml annotations but have no idea how to add the DOCTYPE line.

Can anyone point me in the right direction please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't find any nice way to do it using annotations to build the xml object, so workaround was to create the xml as a string then parse it as text/plain to create an okhttp3 RequestBody and .execute that.

```
String xml = "<!DOCTYPE ourapi SYSTEM \"dtdName.dtd\">\n" +
            "<otherStuff>"\n+
            "</otherStuff>";


RequestBody requestBody = 
         RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), xml);

return ourApi.post(requestBody).execute();
```